# Given Eigen vector find eigen values.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The vector $
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1\\
    2 \\
    -1 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
$ is an Eigen vector of $A=$$
  \begin{bmatrix}
    -2 & 2 &-3\\
    2&1 & -6\\
    -1&-2 & 0\\
  \end{bmatrix}
$. One of the Eigen value of $A$ is

$(A)\ \ 1$  $\ \ \ (B)\ \ 2$ $\ \ \ (C)\ \ 5$ $\ \ \ (D)\ \ -1$

The way I tried to solve is like this

$AX=\lambda X$

$    \begin{bmatrix}
    -2 & 2 &-3\\
    2&1 & -6\\
    -1&-2 & 0\\
  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    1\\
    2 \\
    -1 \\
  \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
    5\\
    10 \\
    -5 \\
  \end{bmatrix}=5\begin{bmatrix}
    1\\
    2 \\
    -1 \\
  \end{bmatrix}$

So, $5$ is the correct option. I am looking for quick alternate ways to solve this problem.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenvector assumption is redundant for this problem. But *using* this extra information actually gives you a quick way to solve it, as you did.

I don't think there is any "quicker" way to do this problem (except for looking directly at the solution manual...).

Comment: hahah ok thanks